# Compiler doesn't recognize a method in a private extension as private

Tags: swift

I have the following piece of code:

```
class C {
    private enum E {
        // ...
    }
}

private extension C {
    func f(e: E) {    // error: Method must be declared private because its parameter uses a private type
        // ...
    }
}
```

If I make the erroring method `private`, the compiler error disappears. I'm wondering whether it's a bug in Swift or I'm not getting something?

Comment: “because its parameter uses a private type” is the relevant part. E is private so f(E) needs to be private too

Comment: @WarrenBurton, I think OP's saying Swift should infer it is private and therefor not require the extra keyword. Right, OP?

Comment: @WarrenBurton the method is inside a `private` extension which makes it `private` too. Am I wrong?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth absolutely! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the top level, `private` is equivalent to `fileprivate` – as `private` means only accessible within the enclosing scope (and also same-file extensions), and at the top level, the file *is* that scope.

So what you have here is equivalent to:

```
class C {
    private enum E {
        // ...
    }
}

fileprivate extension C {
    // error: Method must be declared private because its parameter uses a private type.
    func f(e: E) { 
        // ...
    }
}
```

<sup>(and for this reason, I always write `fileprivate` instead of `private` at the top level for clarity)</sup>

which makes the issue slightly easier to understand – the extension method `f` is by default `fileprivate` and therefore accessible within the scope of the entire file, but its parameter is typed as `E`, which is only accessible within the scope of the class `C`.

As you've discovered, you could mark `f` as `private`:

```
class C {
  private enum E {
    // ...
  }
}

fileprivate extension C {
  private func f(e: E) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

or alternatively mark `E` as `fileprivate`:

```
class C {
  fileprivate enum E {
    // ...
  }
}

fileprivate extension C {
  func f(e: E) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

in order to resolve the issue such that the extension method `f` has the same visibility as its parameter type `E`.

Comment: Hamish, thanks for the research and explanation, it's very interesting! Thus, in short, you wouldn't consider this behavior to be a bug, right?

Comment: @ArtemStepanenko Correct, it's working as intended, albeit in a way that's not immediately obvious.

Comment: @Hamish Do you know how can I constraint `RangeReplaceableCollection` `Index` to `BidirectionalIndexType` in Swift 4 ?

Comment: @LeoDabus Hmm, `BidirectionalIndexType` is from the days of the Swift 2 collection indexing model where indices moved themselves. With the new collection model, the only constraint on index types is that they must be `Comparable` (for any type of collection).

Comment: I need access to `last` property while extending `RangeReplaceableCollection` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52065329/swift-better-way-to-remove-a-specific-object-from-an-array/52067229?noredirect=1#comment91101066_52067229